# Enable a 3D sphere/globe in MapBox GL JS, just like Google Maps does it?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, globe

MapBox GL JS looks very close to Google Maps (in 3D mode) up-close, but if you zoom out enough, the world just looks like an endlessly repeating strip of flat 2D world maps, like this:

[image: 1]

If you zoom out in Google Maps, you can see that it's actually rendered on a big sphere, the way Earth actually looks from space:

[image: 2]

How do I enable this look in MapBox GL JS? I mean without using some complicated hack involving third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Globe has now been released in Mapbox GL JS v2.9 and can be enabled as follows:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  projection: 'globe'
});
```

[Example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/globe/)

Answer (score 1):

Globe view with GL JS is currently work in progress, for more information including a working demo see:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10784

According to a Mapbox developer they are trying to make globe view available this fall (2021):

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10784#issuecomment-877066650